# Producing a SOAP web service in Spring - WSDL- XSD Mapping problem

Tags: spring-boot, soap

I´m creating a Soap WebService in Spring Boot, But I have some issues related to the mapping between wsdl and xsd.

1 - In my wsdl file i have the following structure (only a few lines to show the problem)

```
    <wsdl:message name="NotificationRequest">
<wsdl:part name="NotificationMessage" element="xsd1:notification_message"/>
</wsdl:message>
```

2 - In my xsd file i have this mention:

```
 <xsd:element name="notification_message" type="NotificationContainer"/>
```

the notification_message is a NotificationContainer object.

3 - When i had generated the pojos class files (java), i only have the notificationContainer and i don´t have any reference to notification_message....

4 - My problem is what i must to put in endpoint playload to read the notification_message ???

```
@Endpoint
    public class WebServiceEndpoint {
        private static final String NAMESPACE_URI = "something";
        @PayloadRoot(namespace = NAMESPACE_URI, localPart = "NotificationContainer")
        @ResponsePayload
        public NotificationContainer hello(@RequestPayload NotificationContainer request) { 
        }
    }
```

2 OPTION:

```
@Endpoint
    public class WebServiceEndpoint {
        private static final String NAMESPACE_URI = "something";
        @PayloadRoot(namespace = NAMESPACE_URI, localPart = "notification_message")
        @ResponsePayload
        public void hello(@RequestPayload NotificationContainer request) {
        }
    }
```

All these options give me this error:

```
No endpoint mapping found for [SaajSoapMessage {hella.xsd}notification_message]
```

i must to have the an object with name notification_message? How i map the notification_message to NotificationContainer?

Thank you very much! :)